# How to use biggest font in UILabel as possible?

Tags: ios, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

In my case `UILabel` size can change dynamical . If it is bigger I want to have the best fitting, biggest font size. Is it possible to set it in Storyboard or I need calculate the best one programmatically?

Comment: I'm afraid that you'll need to calculate the best one programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 word in the label, you can set a very high font size and, set `AutoShrink -> Minimum Font Size` to a small size. Then in run time app will auto shrink to maximum possible font size. But this doesn't work for if you only have a single word.